# ¿Por que al tratar de mostrarlo en pantalla me sale "undefined" si se supone que lo defini ya en la variable (cel_b_1)?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto, undefined

```
class celBaja {

    detalles (tpcel,color, peso, rpanta, rcam, mram){

        this.tpcel = tpcel;
        this.color = color;
        this.peso = peso;
        this.rpanta = rpanta;
        this.rcam = rcam;
        this.mram = mram;
        this.info = `El celular numero ${this.tpcel} es de color ${this.color} y tiene un peso de ${this.peso}gr, tambien tiene una resolucion de pantalla de ${this.rpanta}px y una camara de ${this.rcam}mpx, ademas cuenta con ${this.mram}Gb de memoria ram `;

    }

    verInfoCel(){

        document.write(this.info)

    }

}

let cel_b_1 = new celBaja(1, "negro", 12, 15, 32, 8);

cel_b_1.verInfoCel()
```

El resultado me salta undefined siempre por que sera?

Comment: El color es "negro" o es "black"?

Answer (score 1):

Fíjate que estas usando una palabra no reservada para definir el constructor de tu clase.
Reemplaza detalles --> constructor

```js
class celBaja {

    constructor (tpcel,color, peso, rpanta, rcam, mram){
        this.tpcel = tpcel;
        this.color = color;
        this.peso = peso;
        this.rpanta = rpanta;
        this.rcam = rcam;
        this.mram = mram;
        this.info = `El celular numero ${this.tpcel} es de color ${this.color} y tiene un peso de ${this.peso}gr, tambien tiene una resolucion de pantalla de ${this.rpanta}px y una camara de ${this.rcam}mpx, ademas cuenta con ${this.mram}Gb de memoria ram `;
    }

    verInfoCel(){
        console.log(this.info)
    }

}

let cel_b_1 = new celBaja(1, "negro", 12, 15, 32, 8);
cel_b_1.verInfoCel()
```

Comment: Despues comentame si esto ayudo con tu inconveniente!

Comment: te edite la respuesta para eliminar la imagen y que tu codigo se ejecute desde un snipped tiene el mismo resultado pero en tiempo real, saludos.

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta del compañero, márcala como aceptada para que la comunidad vea que esta fue la solución a dicho problema. Así los que tengan problemas semejantes puedan tambien beneficiarse.